# Filter Out Rows In Two Filtering Schemes Using IronPython

Tags: ironpython, spotfire, tibco

I have a dashboard that uses two subsets to filter different date ranges. Each subset uses one filtering scheme.

I would like to add the "filter out" functionality to both filtering schemes at once. Is it possible?

Spotfire has the option to right-click -> Marked Rows -> Filter out, but it only affects one filtering scheme at a time (so the user has to manually change the filtering scheme and filter out again).

[image]

Is there an IronPython script that allows me to do that?